# What is the best way to access previous lines in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame result from the yfinance api.

```py
stock = yf.download ('PETR4.SA', start = '2019-01-01', stop = '2020-12-31')
stock.head()

           Open         High      Low       Close Adj        Close Volume
2019-01-02 22.549999 24.200001 22.280001 24.059999 23.284782 104534800
2019-01-03 23.959999 24.820000 23.799999 24.650000 23.855774 95206400
2019-01-04 24.850000 24.940001 24.469999 24.719999 23.923517 72119800
2019-01-07 24.850000 25.920000 24.700001 25.110001 24.300953 1217119
```

I would like to compare the High of a given day with the value of the HIGH of the previous day or 2 or 3 days before or after. How to access the previous lines in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) ?

```
>>> stock.shift(periods=1).head()  # the result is logically deduced.
           Open         High      Low       Close Adj        Close Volume
2019-01-02 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-01-03 22.549999 24.200001 22.280001 24.059999 23.284782 104534800
2019-01-04 23.959999 24.820000 23.799999 24.650000 23.855774 95206400
2019-01-07 24.850000 24.940001 24.469999 24.719999 23.923517 72119800
2019-01-08 24.850000 25.920000 24.700001 25.110001 24.300953 1217119
```

?

Comment: I think you should not hesitate ask a new question. It is hard to tell exactly what your attempt is within the restricted space of these comment boxes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164378/error-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous

Answer (score -1):

pandas is indispensable when working with data frames.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from datetime import datetime
ibm = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols='IBM', start=datetime(2000, 1, 1), end=datetime(2012, 1, 1))
print(ibm['Adj Close'])
```

In order to install the datareader, please follow this link: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader

Comment: The asker is already using Pandas, because yfinance depends on it. If you're specifically recommending pandas_datareader (which also depends on Pandas), I'd recommend clarifying. (One would probably use either yfinance *or* pandas_datareader most of the time, though yfinance does include the ability to overwrite pandas_datareader's Yahoo method.)